# Django: call standard command from a custom command

Tags: django, django-management-command

In my app, i am using a custom system for managing localization strings. In that connection, I have written a custom command that generates `*.po` files. However, after running that command, I have to manually call the `compilemessages` command. What I would like to do is to call the `compilemessages` command from my custom one. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [call_command()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command):

```
from django.core.management import call_command
# generate your *.po files, then
call_command('compilemessages')
```